# ElasticSearch Multi Term Query With Java High-Level REST Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The [java-high-level-rest-client](https://dzone.com/articles/java-high-level-rest-client-elasticsearch) provides a method to search on elasticsearch using a term that Shown below its code

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user", "kimchy"));
```

But I want to do a query on multiple fields like this: "user"="kimchy" and/or "city"="london".

I see the [multi-search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-multi-search.html) query and multi-match query but they don't do what I want.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder
    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user", "kimchy"))
    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("city", "london"));
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);
```

the `filter/must/should` method on `BoolQueryBuilder`, depends on which context you want, if you want "or", you can use `should`.

Answer (score 0):

One can try this.

```
BooleanQuery.Builder booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
            foreach (var term in (s + ',' + t).Split(','))
            {
                booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("content", term)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
            }
            //booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("content", s)), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
            //booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("content", t)), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
            TopDocs hits = searcher.search(booleanQuery.build(), int.MaxValue);
```